# How do I use JQuery to create an onclick javascript link in HTML with quote-including-string parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a link as follows in HTML:

`<a href="javascript:void(0) onclick="print(string)">`

I'm doing this using JQuery as follows:

`html = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="print(\'' + string + '\')">'`

However, I run into problems when `string` itself contains a single quotation mark. Is there any way that I can do something of this sort regardless of the characters contained in `string`? The main ones I'm trying to figure out are both single and double quotation marks.

Best, and thanks for any advice,

Sami

Comment: Using jQuery to create inline javascript seems like an oxymoron ?

Comment: haha @adeneo what has this world come to

Comment: well this is coming from within a processingJS app running in Canvas. creating a new element based out of data in the canvas app to be placed in the parent HTML page. 

string is an element passed into a function (this is just a line from many)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this quite easily by simply encoding the string as a URIComponent before placing it in and then decoding it when you need it.

ie.

```
var NoQuotesString = encodeURIComponent(string);
//to encode the string without quotes

var BringBackMyQuotes = decodeURIComponent(NoQuotesString);
//decodes the string back to the original
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem, but have you already tried the `escape` function?

Like this:

```
html = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="print(\'' + escape(string) + '\')">'
```

Comment: while I ended up using your answer for my problem, i think the one I accepted will be more useful to more people. (both since it's more complete, an since escape won't suffice for some uses).

to anybody using this, `unescape` is how you decode escaped strings.

Answer (score 0):

Since your using jQuery why not use the event listeners it provides?

Give your link an id value:

```
<a href="#" id="someID">anchor</a>
```

Define the desired behavior with jQuery:

```
$('#someID').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();// prevent the default anchor behavior
    $('#someID').text('New anchor text');// this is an example of the functionality
});
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/BfHrW/